# Conditional Formatting: border - not going around entire cell

Tags: excel, format, conditional-statements

Community, I have a simple formula to check to see if a cell is blank.  The conditional formatting works to an extent.  I have a merged cell and the borders go almost all the way around.  It cuts off at the bottom right corner.  My formula information is as follows.

Formula: =($D$5)="" Applies to: =$O$3:$T$3

Thoughts or suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong or if there is another way to get the border to go all the way around?

(Yes I did check to see if all of the borders were selected in the format section)

Comment: I can replicate if I apply to `$O$3:$T$3` then do merge and center.  But if I merge and center first, then apply to `$O$3`, then the border looks fine.

Comment: What's odd is that I'm using Excel 2007.  I tried to reformat by removing the conditional format above it, but the problem only appeared on a different side of the cell.

Comment: I do not.  I only have the two merged cells stacked on top of each other.  Might that cause an issue?

Comment: Could be! I personally avoid merged cells as much as possible in excel =P

Comment: @pnuts  I did try to restart excel and the problem persists.  I don't quite understand.  I have two rules going on at once.  Both rules are looking at different boxes.  The one works just fine.  The second one just adds a bottom border.  It's odd like I said.  In fact, so odd that when that condition becomes true the right border disappears  and the bottom border goes like 3/4 across the bottom.

Comment: @pnuts I finally found the issue.  I had VBA looking at the background color of one of the boxes, and trying to change the format along with the rule.  The VBA itself was causing the error.  Thank you though for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve issue by eliminating VBA code that looked at background color and changed formatting.  VBA code conflicted with conditional formatting rule.